# Experience/community cloud - read only detail page

Tags: community, community-builder, experience-cloud

Need to make a record detail page as read only for experience cloud users 'detail/:recordId'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Conan,
I think you should expand on  your question a little more.
provide a bit more back ground, and bit more end goal, and what investigation you have done already.

Comment: Sure will do. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read Only either comes from the page layout or the FLS (field Level Security) and object level security. You probably want to at the very least remove edit access to that object.
So ensure your Exp Cloud Profiles and Permissions Sets line up with this desire.

Happy to expand on my answer when you have a bit more detail.

UPDATE:
If you want different levels of CRUD, based on attributes of a record, there are a few ways to achieve this, primarily your FLS and object Access needs to be read write.
then you either need to employ Record Types that switch based on the attributes, or use dynamic forms, or build custom pages.

depending on the scale of the statuses and the number of different views and whether it will continue to change.
I would choose to use Record Types and Page layouts in the first instance. This requires some form of workflows to adjust the recordType as status changes.

If you go down a custom path then you can define a setup object or customer settings or custom metadata (but dont) and the status in the data will refer to the custom settings and this will cause the page to render accordingly.

But I am making assumption based on the high level info you have described.

Please Update your question and then it will be able to be upvoted.

Comment: Users can edit the record until certain status and after that status if user searches for the record, it has to turn into read only. For printable view we pass parameter '/p' in the url so guessing some similar easy solution

Comment: Please apply these requirements to your question.
Also good to review the rules of this forum so that you do not get -ve ratings.

add more content to your question and hopefully who ever marked you down will see sense to mark it back up once the question is a good question.

Comment: Also be a proactive contributor to this site and you will slowly gain points. More points that more you can do on this site.